# Ignore Private IP space in the WHERE clause in neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j and cypher queries. I am trying to generate a list of unique public IPs and want to exclude the private IP space in the WHERE clause. What would be the best way to achieve this?
An example of how I am fitting my query is
`MATCH (A:Account)-[R1:RESOURCE]->(B:DNSRecord) WHERE B.value not in [private IP] RETURN B`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, just move the `NOT` before `B.value`, like this:

```
MATCH (A:Account)-[R1:RESOURCE]->(B:DNSRecord) 
WHERE NOT B.value IN [private IP] 
RETURN B
```

Comment: thanks. How should my private IP list look like? Since private IP is a range. How should I define it?

Comment: Can you share some examples?

Comment: Private IP range Eg: 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255.

Comment: WHERE NOT ( 
   10.0. 0.0 < B.value < 10.255. 255.255 OR
   172.16. 0.0 < B.value < 172.31. 255.255 OR
    192.168. 0.0 < B.value < 192.168. 255.255
)

Comment: Ok. You can try the approach suggested by @HakanLofqvist, but check thoroughly. Because I believe IP addresses are stored as strings, and the range comparison, is not as similar as comparing numbers.

Comment: yeah the IPs are string so the above comparison wont work.

Comment: Then the only way is to generate the list of IP's from the application and send it as a parameter to the query.